# JPA CascadeType.ALL does not delete orphans

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am having trouble deleting orphan nodes using JPA with the following mapping

```
@OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "owner")
private List<Bikes> bikes;
```

I am having the issue of the orphaned roles hanging around the database.

I can use the annotation `org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade` Hibernate specific tag but obviously I don't want to tie my solution into a Hibernate implementation.

**EDIT**: It seems JPA 2.0 will include support for this.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

If you are using it with Hibernate, you'll have to explicitly define the annotation `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN`, which can be used in conjunction with JPA `CascadeType.ALL`.

If you don't plan to use Hibernate, you'll have to explicitly first delete the child elements and then delete the main record to avoid any orphan records.

execution sequence

1. fetch main row to be deleted
2. fetch child elements
3. delete all child elements
4. delete main row
5. close session

With JPA 2.0, you can now use the option **orphanRemoval = true**

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="foo", orphanRemoval=true)
```

Comment: thanks I ended up going this route, I think this is a bit of an oversite for the JPA spec.

Comment: The JPA 2.0 standard now has deleteOrphan as an attribute to @OneToMany

If you are using the latest hibernate you can do @OneToMany(..., deleteOrphan=true)

Comment: what is execution sequence when i just update child-elements? will orphan-records be deleted?

Answer (score 113):

If you are using JPA 2.0, you can now use the `orphanRemoval=true` attribute of the `@xxxToMany` annotation to remove orphans.

Actually, `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN` has been deprecated in 3.5.2-Final.

Comment: Actually I think orphanRemoval=true means something else, i.e., delete an object when I remove it from it's parent's collection. See http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html#giqxy

Comment: Please g through Archie's link.

Comment: **orphanRemoval=true** does not work either. It has to be done the old way.

Answer (score 49):

```
╔═════════════╦═════════════════════╦═════════════════════╗
║   Action    ║  orphanRemoval=true ║   CascadeType.ALL   ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║   delete    ║     deletes parent  ║    deletes parent   ║
║   parent    ║     and orphans     ║    and orphans      ║
╠═════════════╬═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╣
║   change    ║                     ║                     ║
║  children   ║   deletes orphans   ║      nothing        ║
║    list     ║                     ║                     ║
╚═════════════╩═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

Comment: What happens if I have `cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = false` and delete the parent? Will it delete children, even though I've specifically told NOT to?

Answer (score 12):

If you are using JPA with EclipseLink, you'll have to set the *@PrivateOwned* annotation.

Documentation: [Eclipse Wiki - Using EclipseLink JPA Extensions - Chapter 1.4 How to Use the @PrivateOwned Annotation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Using_EclipseLink_JPA_Extensions_%28ELUG%29)

Answer (score 7):

you can use @PrivateOwned to delete orphans
e.g

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "masterData", cascade = {
        CascadeType.ALL })
@PrivateOwned
private List<Data> dataList;
```

Comment: Thanks @reshma it should be noted @PrivateOwned is a eclipselink JPA extension.

Answer (score 6):

I just find this solution but in my case it doesn't work:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = MyClass.class, mappedBy = "xxx", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
```

**orphanRemoval = true** has no effect.

Comment: I needed to clean and build before the change came into effect.

Comment: Wow, I've been looking for an hour as to why adding CascadeType.ALL on my ManyToOne wasn't cascading deletes. Cleaned and built and it works. Thanks @maralbjo.

Answer (score 4):

According to [Java Persistence with Hibernate](http://manning.com/bauer2/), *cascade orphan delete* is not available as a JPA annotation.

It is also not supported in JPA XML.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and I wondered why this condition below did not delete the orphans. The list of dishes were not deleted in Hibernate (5.0.3.Final) when I executed a named delete query:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "menuPlan", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Dish> dishes = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then I remembered that I **must not use a named delete query**, but the EntityManager. As I used the `EntityManager.find(...)` method to fetch the entity and then `EntityManager.remove(...)` to delete it, the dishes were deleted as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,  mappedBy = "xxx", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)`.

Remove **targetEntity = MyClass.class**, it works great.

Answer (score 1):

For the records, in OpenJPA before JPA2 it was @ElementDependant.

Answer (score 0):

I was using one to one mapping , but child was not getting deleted JPA was giving foreign key violation

After using orphanRemoval = true , issue got resolved

Comment: @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
 @JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_OID")
  private Child child;