# Hibernate deleting orphans when updating collection

Tags: java, hibernate, orphan

I'm finding that orphan records aren't being deleted when removing from a collection in Hibernate.  I must be doing something simple wrong, (this is Hibernate-101!), but I can't find it..

Given the following:

```
public class Book {
    @ManyToOne
    @NotNull
    Author author;
}
public class Author
{
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    List<Book> books;
}
```

And the following update code:

```
Author author = authorDAO.get(1);
Book book = author.getBooks().get(0);
author.getBooks().remove(0);
authorDAO.update(author);
```

AuthorDAO snippet:

```
@Override
public void update(T entity) {
    getSession().update(entity);
}
```

The following test the fails:

```
Author author = author.get(1);
assertEquals(0,author.getBooks().size()); // Passes
Book dbBook = bookDAO.get(book.getId())
assertNull(dbBook); // Fail!  dbBook still exists!
assertFalse(author.getBooks().contains(dbBook) // Passes!
```

In summary, I'm finding:

- While book is removed from the Author's collection of books, it still exists in the database
- If I examine `book.getAuthor().getBooks()`, book does not exist in that collection

This "feels" like I'm not flushing the session or forcing an update appropriately - but I'm not sure where I should be doing that.  Along that vein, other points that may be impacting:

- I'm performing the above in a JUnit test decorated with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`
- I originally hit this problem inside an update routine which is decorated with `@Transactional`, however, I have since recreated it in a plain old JUnit test.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**   Thanks for all the feedback already. Further to comments below, I've added the `@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)` to the parent, so it's now:

```
public class Author
{
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    List<Book> books;
}
```

I'm still finding the same results. I MUST be missing something simple.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're not doing anything wrong. You're just not removing the child entity. You can either do this with an explicit remove() of the child entity (in addition to what you're doing) or use that annotation that causes orphan records to be deleted.

Also, it's worth mentioning that `CascadeType.DELETE` won't delete orphans either. That means something else. See [JPA CascadeType.ALL does not delete orphans.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306144/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-delete-orphans)

Basically to do this automatically you'll want this on the collection in the parent:

```
org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN
```

Comment: I've added this annotation, but it's still not working - same results as before.

Comment: Are you also setting the author reference in the book to null?

Comment: No, I thought that was the point of the DELETE_OPRHAN annotation?

Comment: You still have to manage the Java relationships yourself. That means you have to set the parent to null in the child if the relationship is bidirectional.

Answer (score 46):

for people searching for their solution: Now in Hibernate, resp. JPA 2.0, this is the right way:

```
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true)
```

Answer (score 3):

The cascade option in the `@OneToMany` annotation is a array, what you want is:

```
@OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
```

Comment: wont CascadeType.ALL cover CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN too ?

Comment: This answer is 9 years old now. It is probably not relevant any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following annoation if you want 'transitive dependency' behavour.

@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)

Answer (score 0):

please add @onDelete maybe this work for you

```
public class Author
{
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
    List<Book> books;
}
```

Comment: Hi.  This also has no effect.

Comment: do you commit your session or flush it after delete?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're might be missing the **mappedBy** annotation.  Try:

```
public class Book {
  @ManyToOne
  @NotNull
  Author author;
}
public class Author {
  @OneToMany(mappedBy="author", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  List<Book> books;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party and I realize a lot has been said already on this topic but IMHO I would not use delete-orphans as a cascade option. I would rather delete child associations manually before deleting the parent. One slight oversight... and a long chain of associations can be deleted in a second. Yes! I agree that this may be exactly one would want in some circumstances.