# @OneToOne with CascadeType.ALL not getting deleted?

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to delete any attached child objects when removing a parent from DB. But it does not work:

```
@Entity
public class ParentEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;    

    //must remain unidirectional
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private MyEntity my;

}

@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    private String text;
}

public interface ParentEntityRepository extends CrudRepository<ParentEntity, Long> {}
```

When I execute:

```
@Autowired
private ParentEntityRepository  dao;

@Transactional
public void removeId(long id) {
      dao.delete(id);
}
```

Result:
`MyEntity` row still exists in DB! Why?

Comment: What does `dao.delete(id);` look like?

Comment: It's a spring `CrudRepository`, added above.

Comment: Is the parent entity row itself deleted from db?

Comment: Yes the parent row is removed completely.

Comment: Are you using EclipseLink or Hibernate?

Comment: I'm using hibernate, that's why I tagged the question with `hibernate`.

Comment: which version of hibernate are you using?

Comment: `hibernate-4.3.10.FINAL`

Comment: Have you tried to move the Relation to `MyEntity` and thus making ParentEntity the "owning side"?

Comment: No, but I also have to keep the relation owning as is.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN)
private MyEntity my;
```

If it doesn't works you can try this:

[Hibernate deleting orphans when updating collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304862/hibernate-deleting-orphans-when-updating-collection)

Comment: If you look at my example that's 100% what I have and which does not work!

Comment: I'm not updating a collection, but a @OneToOne object reference. Please read the question first.