# What is cascade="delete-orphan" in hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

Can anyone help me what is the exact funtionality of cascade="delete-orphan?

It is like when a parent is deleted, all childs associated with a parent will not be deleted or will be deleted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between DELETE\_ORPHAN and DELETE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377585/what-is-the-difference-between-delete-orphan-and-delete)

Comment: You should do a better job of researching before you post a question like this.

Comment: @Tim yes thanks for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/) and searching for "delete-orphan" in the text leads to the following explanation:

> A special cascade style, delete-orphan, applies only to one-to-many associations, and indicates that the delete() operation should be applied to any child object that is removed from the association. Using annotations there is no CascadeType.DELETE-ORPHAN equivalent. Instead you can use the attribute orphanRemoval as seen in Example 11.4, “@OneToMany with orphanRemoval”. If an entity is removed from a @OneToMany collection or an associated entity is dereferenced from a @OneToOne association, this associated entity can be marked for deletion if orphanRemoval is set to true.

The documentation is your friend. Read it.

Comment: yes thank u..sure i'll read.eventhough it is silly question.u tried to help me.