# Removing child from collection using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, one-to-many

I'm using JPA over Hibernate in my web-app. Here are two entities (only getters are shown):

```
class Child {
  private Parent parent;

  @ManyToOne(optional=false)
  @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="parent_id", nullable=false, updatable=false)
  public Parent getParent() {
    return parent;
  }
}

class Parent {
  private Collection<Child> children;

  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="parent", cascade={CascadeType.ALL})
  public Collection<Child> getChildren() {
    return children;
  }
}
```

As you see `Parent` and `Child` relate as "one-to-many".

Now I need to load a `Parent` instance, remove some or all children and save the changes. Below is code which  does not work for me:

```
Parent p = entityManager.find(Parent.class, 12345L); // load entity
p.getChildren().clear(); // remove all children
entityManager.merge(p); // try to save
```

Child entities are not remove in the example above. Now I have to manually call `entityManager.remove()` for each child.

Is there any easier way to manage child collection?

Please notice that I don't want to use Hibernate-specific functionality, only pure JPA.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JPA CascadeType.ALL does not delete orphans.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306144/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-delete-orphans)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

For JPA 2.0 you can set  [`orphanRemoval=true`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#orphanRemoval%28%29) of the `@OneToMany`

For JPA 1.0, you should use hibernate-specific annotations. That is the `@Cascade` annotation (instead of the `cascade` attribute), with a value of

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.ALL, CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN})
```

Hibernate 3.5+ implement JPA 2.0

Comment: Is there any solution for JPA 1.0? I'm not ready to change JPA implementor.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good way. set orphanRmoval, when merge can delete the orphan child

Comment: With regard to orphanRemoval how exactly does the EntityManager tell the difference between an object that was explicitly removed from the collection (and hence, needs to be deleted in the DB) versus an object that's not in the collection because it was never loaded to begin with? (i.e. because the one-to-many collection is lazy)? Or does it only work in EAGER collections?

Comment: it compares the state of the collection to the state of the database. So if something is missing in the collection (regardless of the reason) but it present in the database, it is deleted from the database

Comment: Thanks. The @Cascade was the only solution for me, even using JPA2.0. Weird.