# Update all table data at a time in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

Is it possible to update all table data in one query?

I have a Database table Person and corresponding Entiry PersonEntity, I can get all Person data vi a JPA in a list such as List personAll.

I have several CRUD operation on personAll instance, I want to reflect all these changes to the Database in one hand using Hibernate JPA

In other words  I want content of Person Table is replaced with new content of personAll instance?

Actually long solution way of this question is execute several insert, delete and update operations. But there should be a easy way of doing it?

I can do similar thing when there are two tables Shool Student table if there is OneToMany relation between eash other? [Hibernate JPA value removing OneToMany relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14358188/hibernate-jpa-value-removing-onetomany-relation)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many rows there are in your table.

If you load all the rows into a Hibernate session and modify the returned instances as required, any changes will be automatically persisted to the database by Hibernate when the session is flushed.

The reason it depends on the size is that if you load the contents of a huge table into a Hibernate session you risk out of memory errors and even if you don't run out of memory the flush will be very slow since every entity in the session much be checked for modifications.

Comment: There will not be much more row on the table, I think maximum 100. So How I can reflexct all these changes into DB table? I mean I am expecting a method that takes List personAll instance, and all insert, delete and update opeations take automatically? I do not want to involve into these operation, I just focus on List personAll instance, be sure that Table in DB will be same after persit operation.

Comment: Hibernate works by tracking all loaded objects in the session. Any changes you make to them will be automatically persisted. So you don't need to pass your list to a method. Just load them , change them and close your session (making sure it's flushed first). Obviously, that's for updates (call session#delete for each instance you want to be removed from the database and session#save for new objects).