# SpringMVC + hibernate @ManyToMany, controller losing collection during update

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I got two entities `Employee.class` and `Project.class` with `@ManyToMany` relation between them.

When I'm trying to update `Employee` and add another `Project` to it via JSP form, controller makes `Set<Project>`empty. So, when I submit the form, hibernate instead of adding another project to `Set<Project>`, makes this:

```
 Hibernate: update employee set ....(IT'S OK)
 Hibernate: update project set...(IT'S OK)
 Hibernate: delete from employee_project where employee_id=?(IT'S NOT OK)
```

**Employee.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee{

//other fields 

@ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, 
        cascade=CascadeType.ALL) 
@JoinTable(name="employee_project",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="employee_id"),
     inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="project_id"))
private Set<Project> projects = new HashSet<>();

 public Set<Project> getProjects() {
    return projects;
}

public void setProjects(Set<Project> projects) {
    this.projects = projects;
}
```

**Project.class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="project")
public class Project {

@ManyToMany(fetch= FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="projects")
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();

public Set<Employee> getEmployees() {
    return employees;
}

public void setEmployees(Set<Employee> employees) {
    this.employees = employees;
}
```

**EmployeeController.class**

```
@GetMapping("/employeeForm")
public String showEmployeeForm(Model theModel) {

    Employee theEmployee = new Employee();
    theModel.addAttribute("employee", theEmployee);
    theModel.addAttribute("projects", projectService.getProjectsIdMap());

    return "employee-form";
}

@GetMapping("/employee/{id}/updateEmployee")
public String updateEmployee(@PathVariable("id") Long employeeId, Model theModel) {
    //HERE MY Set<Project> IS FULL OF PROJECTS
    theModel.addAttribute("employee", employeeService.getEmployee(employeeId)); 

    theModel.addAttribute("projects", projectService.getProjectsIdMap());

    return "employee-form";
}
@PostMapping("/saveEmployee")
public String saveOrUpdateEmployee(@ModelAttribute("employee") 
   Employee theEmployee) {

 //HERE MY Set<Project> IS EMPTY
        theEmployee.getProjects()
           .add(projectService
             .getProject(theEmployee.getProjectId()));

        employeeService.saveEmployee(theEmployee);
        return "redirect:/employees/employee/" + theEmployee.getId();

}
```

**employee-form.jsp**

```
 <form:form action="/employee_manager/employees/saveEmployee"
        modelAttribute="employee" method="POST">

        <form:hidden path="id"/>

            <form:select path="projectId">
                <form:options items="${projects}" />
            </form:select>

            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </div>
    </form:form>
```

**Employee.Repository (DAO)**

```
 public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    session.saveOrUpdate(employee);
}
```

**Employee.Service**

```
 @Transactional
public void saveEmployee(Employee employee) {
    employeeRepository.saveEmployee(employee);

}
```

DB structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gP6jr.png)

It looks like somewhere spring set a new collection instead of adding to existing one.

I was trying to debug the app flow and follow `Set<Projects>` and I know that this collection losess all values in `saveOrUpdateEmployee` method. I can't figure out where did I make mistake. Thanks for your help.

Comment: might help . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738934/jpa-removing-child-from-collection?rq=1

Comment: the `cascadeType` shouldn't pose any problem here. maybe the `saveOrUpdateEmployee`, the project isn't saved in the DB and therefore it can't be added and this might cause it to set a new one.

Comment: I agree that Cascading seems to be ok. Maybe during passing Employee to `saveOrUpdateEmployee` method loses reference to `Set<Projects>`.

Answer (score 0):

I found possible cause of my problem. When I submit the update form Spring creates new Instance of my `Employee.class` which means that `Set<Project>` becoming a new empty set. Since I'm passing in `<form:hidden path="id">` id of my Employee, hibernate override all my values in DB including my collection of Projects.

Now I wonder how to prevent such behavior?
`<form:hidden path="projects">` doesn't work.

Using `@InitBinder` -> `binder.setDisallowedFields({"projects"})` doesn't work either.