# alternative way for many-to-many relationship in jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

How to write code with many-to-many relationship without using jpa `@manytomany` annotation? For example for two classes **Software** and for **Tags**. When i delete Tag - it removes all software. I tried to do it with `@manytomany` annotation using various approaches but it does not work. I have seen something similar to my question in this site but any gives the code sample. (I guess it should be `@OneToMany` relationships in both sides, but it would be great to take a code).

Or how to do it with using `@manytomany` if it possible.

More info: if we have soft1, soft2 <--> tag1, and soft2 <--> tag2, and we delete tag1, then only soft1 should be deleted. Does hibernate can handle it?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to do a cascade-delete on a many-to-many relationship?

Comment: maybe it's somehow related to DELETE_ORPHAN

Comment: @user369759 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306144/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-delete-orphans

Comment: Hi ! I also have the same requirement. I have a @ManyToMany relationship. Now what I need is, if I delete tag2, then only tag2 and any assoiciation in tag_soft table should be deleted and soft2 should not be deleted. and if i delete soft2 then soft2 and any association in tag_soft table should be deleted but tag1 and tag2 should no be deleted. Could you help me in this ?

Comment: you should find and delete assassinations by hand to resolve constrains - delete in your objects and then save() changes and only after this delete your object. all this you may want to do in the context of one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade(
   {org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.PERSIST, 
    org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.MERGE, 
    org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REFRESH, 
    org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DETACH, 
    org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN}
)
```

This is to remove org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.REMOVE from the cascade to avoid the following scenario

- You delete Software with id:5
- hibernate deletes Tags with id:5 and 7
- ALL the rows of software tagged with those ids are deleted, and the cascade starts again, so you might end up with an empty DB.