# One to Many relationship JPA/Hibernate removing links

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, jpa

I have bidirectional relationship setup as follows:

```
class Child{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinTable(name = "CHILDREN_WITH_PARENT", 
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "CHILD_ID")}, 
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")}
    )
    private Parent parent;
}

class Parent{
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    Set<Child> childrens = new HashSet<Child>();

    public void persistOrMerge() {
        EntityManager em = entityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        try {
            if (em.contains(this))
                return;
            if (id == null || id == 0) {
                this.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                em.persist(this);
            } else {
                Parent prev = em.find(Parent.class, this.id);
                if (prev == null) {
                    em.persist(this);
                } else{
                    this.setCreatedDate(new Date());
                    em.merge(this);
                }
            }
            em.flush();
            em.getTransaction().commit();

        }  finally {
            em.close();

        }
    }

}
```

On my client side I have following code (GWT + EntityProxy)

```
Set<ChildProxy> children  = new HashSet<ChildProxy>();
if(childIsNew)
   child = request.create(Children.class)
else
   child = request.edit(oldChild)
children.add(child);
//If children are deleted, they are not contained in the set
//we are sending back to server
parent.setChildren(children)
parent.persistOrMerge();
```

**This code only works for adding new children. Removing of children from parent does not work even if parent class receives an empty children set. The linkages in JOIN table are not removed.**

Can you please tell where I am missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: my understanding is since objects are being managed by entitymanager, it will remove children which are not present in the new set that it received

Comment: Could you show what setChildren does exactly? I don't see any mistakes.

Comment: setChildren is a simple accessor method

Comment: public void setChildren(Set<Child> children) {
  this.children = children;
}

Answer (score 6):

I will start by saying that is a really bad idea that the entity is the one using the entity manager directly.

The EntityManager.merge() method returns the actual merged instance, this implies that in your code, when you issue

```
em.merge(this)
```

You have no guarantee whatsoever that the merged instance corresponds to "this" anymore, and from that point on you may see all kinds of logical problems.

If you do not think this is such a big deal, your problem should be solved by turning on orphan removal on the OneToMany side of the relationship, provided that the children are not being used anywhere else in other relationships. Otherwise you will have to do the merging manually.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
Set<Child> childrens = new HashSet<Child>();
```

The JPA 2.0 specification states that

Associations that are specified as OneToOne or OneToMany support use of the orphanRemoval
option. The following behaviors apply when orphanRemoval is in effect:

- If an entity that is the target of
  the relationship is removed from the
  relationship (by setting the
  relationship to null or removing the
  entity from the relationship
  collection), the remove operation
  will be applied to the entity being
  orphaned. The remove operation is
  applied at the time of the flush
  operation. The orphanRemoval
  functionality is intended for
  entities that are privately "owned"
  by their parent entity. Portable
  applications must otherwise not
  depend upon a specific order of
  removal, and must not reassign an
  entity that has been orphaned to
  another relationship or otherwise
  attempt to persist it. If the entity
  being orphaned is a detached, new,or
  removed entity, the semantics of
  orphanRemoval do not apply.
- If the remove operation is applied to
  a managed source entity, the remove
  operation will be cascaded to the
  relationship target in accordance
  with the rules of section 3.2.3, (and
  hence it is not necessary to specify
  cascade=REMOVE for the
  relationship)[20].

Comment: I understand what you are trying to say, but that will still be a non-persistence layer issue. On the other hand, in my case, even the underlying MySQL tables contain linkages which should have ideally been removed.

Comment: if that is not issue your problem is solver turning on orphanRemoval in the @OneToMany side of the relationship.

Comment: children should exist even after parent dies so correct me if I am wrong but I don't think orphanRemoval=true will be suitable solution in my case. All I want to do is remove the linkages. My understanding was EM will do it for me. Guess, I will have to do it manually

Answer (score 1):

```
// In the entity class of Parent1 write a method to unlink parent2
public void unLinkParent2(Parent2 parent2)
{
    //remove columns from the link table, pertaining to the parent2
    getParent2Collection().remove(parent2);
    // using the parent2 object remove 'this' parent1 entity link columns
    parent2.getParent1Collection().remove(this);
}
```

```
Parent1:        Parent2:        LinkP1-P2
--------------------------------------------------
Id1(PK)         Id2(PK)         Id1 (composite PK)
name1           Name2           Id2 (composite PK)
```

`Id1` and `Id2` of the Link table together is a primary key referring to `Parent1` and `Parent2` tables.

Answer (score 1):

The ManyToOne mapping controls the relationship - you have marked the OneToMany as mappedby the child's relation to its parent.  This means that changes to the relationship are only picked up if merged from the child side.  Because children removed from the parents list are no longer in it, merge cannot be cascaded to them, and any changes in them are never persisted to the database.

As others pointed out, orphan removal will allow for any children not in the list to be deleted on merge.  This might be overkill when all you want is the relationship nulled out.  In this scar, you can probably reverse the relationship so that it is owned by the parent.  That will ensure the relation gets updated, but any changes in removed children will still not get picked up.  The only way to get those changes picked up is to add the children to a new parent that gets merged, or to merge them independently.  If they can exist without a parent, calling persist/merge on them directly is the better option.

Answer (score 0):

This question is related:
[JPA CascadeType.ALL does not delete orphans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306144/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-delete-orphans)

Comment: I don't get any exceptions. Tables are created by EntityManager on initialization.

Comment: Deleting parent does delete child so I am not sure if it is related to CascadeType.ALL not deleting orphans

Comment: If i understood that correctly, nulling the parents reference to the child is different to deleting the child (em.remove(child)). So this may be related, just try it. Btw calling em.remove(oldChild) should solve your problem.