# JPA CascadeType.ALL not deleting child records

Tags: java, jpa

Consider this use case.

```
class Category {
   @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
   List<Application> applications = new ArrayList<Application>();
}

class Application {
   @ManyToOne
   Category category;       
}
```

I understand that, On this case, when category will be deleted, application will also be deleted. But who takes care of join table? The Category_Application table generated for the relation.

Answer (score 3):

The join table rows should always be deleted, regardless of `cascade`.

For a bi-directional `ManyToMany` to owning (non-`mappedBy`) side will delete the rows.

Since you have a `ManyToOne` back, it seems you should be using a `mappedBy`, not a join table.

Is the issue that they are not being deleted, or are you getting a constraint error before they are deleted?  Also ensure you collection is not empty when you call `remove()`. Try also removing everything from the collection before calling `remove`.

Comment: I James, Thanks for your reply. No I am not getting any error, but join table's rows are not deleted. That is the only problem I am having.

When I delete the entity, i am not sure if that entity has collection filled up with join values. but isnt it that the table reference should delete it by default even if i don't have the collection filled up? Because of the cascade type i have mentioned?

Comment: If the collection was empty, the a delete is not required as there are no rows to delete.  How did you get the object you are removing?  What JPA provider and version are you using?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like this is the same issue as:

[JPA CascadeType.ALL does not delete orphans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306144/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-delete-orphans)

Basically, when you have a `@OneToMany`, JPA assumes by default that the child object has an independent lifecycle and may be associated to multiple parents.  Deleting the parent does not necessarily delete the child.  Specifying `orphanRemoval=true` in JPA 2.0 (or Eclipselink `@PrivateOwned` or Hibernate `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN`) tells JPA to remove the child records when the parent is deleted.

If you always want to tie the child record lifecyle to its parent, you might also want to consider @ElementCollection instead of @OneToMany, which will give similar behavior but not let you persist child objects independently of the parent.  (i.e., the child objects of an @ElementCollection are not @Entities.)