# How to enforce orphan deletion on a ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, many-to-one

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = COL_GROUP_ID, nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = COL_ID)
@OnDelete(action = CASCADE)
@Cascade(value = DELETE_ORPHAN)
private Group group;
```

How to enforce orphan deletion on a ManyToOne relationship, the above code snippet worked for us in Hibernate 3.3.x, but post migration to 3.6.5.Final it shows up as a WARNING in the code. is there a equivalent flag like orphanRemoval = true which is applied on a @OneToMany notation?

Comment: Is there an API?  Do you have the link?  Have you [searched SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306144/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-delete-orphans) or [google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&client=firefox-a&hs=PLT&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=hibernate+3.6.5+cascade+delete+manytoone&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=)?

Comment: @Atreys - The above link talks about support for orphanRemoval on a @OneToMany annotation. We have some legacy code (from Hibernate 3.3.x) which we are trying to migrate and I didn't see any support for orphanRemoval on a @ManyToOne annotation. Hence the question

Answer (score 0):

You can not apply **ORPHAN_REMOVAL** to *MANY_TO_ONE* side.

Suppose you have an entity **City** which has *@OneToMany* **Citizen** and on the other side you have *@ManyToOne* **City** in **Citizen** entity. In your scenario removing one citizen will lead to removing the whole city, thus **ORPHAN_REMOVAL** is only applicable to *XXX_TO_Many* side