# HIbernate update with null on onetomany relation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, exception, one-to-many

I have the following tables :

- PRODUCT (id_product, name)
- PROPERTY (id_property, name)
- PRODUCT_PROPERTIES (id_product, id_property)

(all the fields are not nullable)

And the following hibernate mapping :

```
class Product {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="product")
    @Cascade({CascadeType.ALL})
    private Set<ProductProperties> productProperties = new HashSet<ProductProperties)(0);

    (...)    
}
```

When I update the product class by adding or removing rows from the "productProperties" field, the rows are updated correctly in the PRODUCT_PROPERTIES table.

The problem is that when "productProperties" is null or empty, Hibernate throws a ConstraintViolationException.

Since I need the "productProperties" to be empty sometimes, is there a proper solution to this problem (something like @ZeroToMany annotation) ?

Comment: What's the stack trace of the exception, and the code causing it to be thrown? How is the ProductProperties entity defined?

Comment: You have enable orphan deletion. Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306144/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-delete-orphans.

Comment: @DevBlanked thanks for you answer, "orphanRemoval=true" does indeed the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is given by Dev Blanked in the comments. 
This is the solution :

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="foo", orphanRemoval=true)
```