# In hibernate even though I set cascade type to ALL, but why did I still receive a foreign key violation exception when deleting?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

My database has two table. One of University, another is Faculty. They are one to many relationship

```
package server.hibernate.domain;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;





@Entity
@Table(name = "UNIVERSITY")
public class University implements Serializable{


    private Long _id;
    private int _version;
    private String _universityName;
    private String _countryLocated;
    private Set<Faculty> _faculties = new HashSet<Faculty>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return _id;
    }
    public void setId(Long _id) {
        this._id = _id;
    }

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    public int getVersion() {
        return _version;
    }

    public void setVersion(int _version) {
        this._version = _version;
    }

    @Column(name = "UNIVERSITY_NAME", nullable=false)
    public String getUniversityName() {
        return _universityName;
    }
    public void setUniversityName(String _universityName) {
        this._universityName = _universityName;
    }

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_LOCATED")
    public String getCountryLocated() {
        return _countryLocated;
    }
    public void setCountryLocated(String _countryLocated) {
        this._countryLocated = _countryLocated;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="university", targetEntity=Faculty.class, orphanRemoval=true, fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public Set<Faculty> getFaculties() {
        return _faculties;
    }
    public void setFaculties(Set<Faculty> faculties) {
        this._faculties = faculties;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return new String("UniversityID:"+_id
                + " UniversityName:"+_universityName
                +" CountryLocated:"+_countryLocated);
    }





}
```

This is what I have set in University class.

```
package server.hibernate.domain;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Version;

@Entity
@Table(name="FACULTY")
public class Faculty implements Serializable{

    private Long _id;
    private int _version;
    private String _facultyName;
    private String _deanName;
    private University _university;
    private Set<Student> _students = new HashSet<Student>();

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return _id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    @Version
    @Column(name = "VERSION")
    public int getVersion() {
        return _version;
    }
    public void setVersion(int version) {
        this._version = version;
    }

    @Column(name="FACULTY_NAME", nullable=false)
    public String getFacultyName() {
        return _facultyName;
    }
    public void setFacultyName(String facultyName) {
        this._facultyName = facultyName;
    }

    @Column(name="DEAN_NAME")
    public String getDeanName() {
        return _deanName;
    }
    public void setDeanName(String dean_name) {
        this._deanName = dean_name;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "UNIVERSITY_ID", nullable=false)
    public University getUniversity() {
        return _university;
    }
    public void setUniversity(University university) {
        this._university = university;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="faculty", targetEntity=Student.class, orphanRemoval=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    public Set<Student> getStudents() {
        return _students;
    }
    public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
        this._students = students;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return new String("FacultyID:"+_id
                +" FacultyName:"+_facultyName
                +" DeanName:"+_deanName);
    }


}
```

This is my faculty class
But when I use sessionFactory.delete(university). I still have this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not delete: [server.hibernate.domain.University#1]; SQL [delete from UNIVERSITY where ID=? and VERSION=?]; constraint ["FKE9B72644368E5BBD: PUBLIC.FACULTY FOREIGN KEY(UNIVERSITY_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.UNIVERSITY(ID)"; SQL statement:
delete from UNIVERSITY where ID=? and VERSION=? [23503-160]]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [server.hibernate.domain.University#1]
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:643)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:793)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:664)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.removeUniversity(Unknown Source)
    at main.TestHibernateMain.test(TestHibernateMain.java:73)
    at main.TestHibernateMain.main(TestHibernateMain.java:22)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not delete: [server.hibernate.domain.University#1]
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2710)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2893)
    at org.hibernate.action.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:656)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FKE9B72644368E5BBD: PUBLIC.FACULTY FOREIGN KEY(UNIVERSITY_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.UNIVERSITY(ID)"; SQL statement:
delete from UNIVERSITY where ID=? and VERSION=? [23503-160]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:398)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowRefTable(ConstraintReferential.java:415)
    at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:291)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:861)
    at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:878)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:98)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:73)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:219)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2692)
    ... 20 more
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show the whole entity class and the whole stacktrace and the code where you delete the entity?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/306144/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-delete-orphans

Comment: did you try setting the 'university_id' of faculty to be nullable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by myself.

It is a fetch problem.
When I try remove University by using sessionFactory.delete(university), this university does not fetch any faculties. So the removal will not be cascade enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This because you are trying to delete the UNIVERSITY which is associated with other faculties 
thus you have to first delete associated faculties before deleting the university.

Comment: Did not orphan removal automatically do this?

Comment: could you please add your table structure here and also set hibernate log level to debug so that you can get more information about it..
also add code of Faculty entity class...