# Deleting children of OneToMany relationship not working

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, spring-data

I have problem with deleting from database childs from OneToMany relationship.

Here are my classses:

```
public class Question {

 private Set<Answer> answers
/.................

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "question", orphanRemoval = true)
  public Set<Answer> getAnswers() {
    return this.answers;
  }

/.................
}
```

And Answer class:

```
public class Answer {

private Question question
/............

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID", nullable = false)
  public Question getQuestion() {
    return this.question;
  }

/...........
}
```

And I'am trying to remove question and all its answers like this:

```
public void deleteQuestions(List<Question> questions){

    for(Question question : questions){
      Question databaseQuestion = questionRepository.findOne(question.getId());
      for(Answer answer : databaseQuestion.getAnswers()){
        answerRepository.delete(answer.getId());
      }
      questionRepository.delete(databaseQuestion);
    }
  }
```

And I'm getting:

```
ORA-02292: integrity constraint (DATABASE_NAME.ANSWER_QUESTION_FK) violated - child record found
```

I have no idea what is wrong.
When I put `CascadeType.ALL` on `Question getAnswers()` i still get the same problem.
I am using Hibernate ORM with Spring Data.
Also when I force app to show sql commands, I can see that Hibernate isn't even trying to remove Answers, there is only one delete - on question.

Comment: It might not be executing for loop of answers! Try to debug your code.

Comment: Have you tried to describe a cascadeType?

Comment: I am sure, that for loop executes, there is exactly one answer for that question.

Comment: Okay. Can you try to delete question by Id?

Comment: When I delete question by Id, still same problem.

Comment: Can you debug your code and check on which line this exception is coming?

Comment: Sure, it is:  questionRepository.delete(databaseQuestion.getId());

Comment: **ORA-02292** occurs when child is not deleted. So you need to make sure your for loop of answers works as expected.

Comment: I know, what ORA-02292 means, and I am sure that my for loop works as expected, I think there is some problem with mappings.

Answer (score 0):

Try cascade, use like below

```
@OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "question",orphanRemoval=true)
```

this link your answer
[JPA CascadeType.ALL does not delete orphans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306144/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-delete-orphans)

Comment: Still same result, CascadeType.ALL, and clean, rebuild project as suggested in link.

Comment: From link: If you are using it with Hibernate, you'll have to **explicitly** define the annotation `CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN`, which can be used in **conjunction** with JPA `CascadeType.ALL`.