# Java JPA/Hibernate cascade delete

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I am using `Java8`, `JPA`, `Hibernate 5.2.1.Final`, `Spring 4.3.1.RELEASE` and `MySQL`.

Tables:

As you can see, I have a `job` table joined to a `location_job` tables, making use of the join table `job_location`.

```
+---------+         +--------------+        +---------------+
|   job   |         | job_location |        |  location_job |
+---------+         +--------------+        +---------------+
|   ID    |         |   JOB_ID     |        |     ID        |
|         |         |   LOC_ID     |        |     LAT       |
|         |         |              |        |     LONG      |
+---------+         +--------------+        +---------------+
```

I am performing a **delete** on the `job` table, and also want to delete the corresponding entries on the `job_location` and `location_job` tables.

Code:

Currently, my code deletes successfully from the `job` and `job_location` tables, but does not delete the corresponding entries from the `location_job` table.

**Job.java**

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "job_location", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "LOC_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
private Set<LocationJob> locations;
```

**JobDaoImpl.java**

```
@Repository("jobDao")
public class JobDaoImpl extends JpaDao<Long, Job> implements JobDao {

    @Override
    public boolean delete(Job job) {
        Set<LocationJob> locations = job.getLocations();
        if (locations != null) {
            for (LocationJob location : locations) {
                entityManager.remove(location);
            }
            job.getLocations().clear();
        }       
        entityManager.remove(job);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**JpaDao.java**

```
public class JpaDao<I, T extends AbstractDomain<I>> {

    protected Class<T> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager entityManager;

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    protected JpaDao() {
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        this.entityClass = (Class<T>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[1];
    }

    protected void remove(T entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }
}
```

**Question**

When I delete from the `job` table, how can I make it also delete from the `location_job` table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306144/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-delete-orphans).

I needed to add `orphanRemoval=true`:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval=true)
@JoinTable(name = "job_location", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "LOC_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", unique = true) })
private Set<LocationJob> locations;
```