# Spring Boot JPA many to many delete cascade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

So i have a MyUser entity which refers to a Role entity with a many to many relationship.
But when i try to delete the user, i always get the errror that the user_id is always referenced on the user_role jointable...

I have already tried every cascade type... but didn't get the solution
Please help
Thanks

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class MyUser {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    
    ... Other properties ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Collection<Role> roles;

// getters setters

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String role;

// getters setters
}
```

Comment: maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306144/jpa-cascadetype-all-does-not-delete-orphans

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it stated in the [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-many-to-many):

> For `@ManyToMany` associations, the `REMOVE` entity state transition doesn’t make sense to be cascaded because it will propagate beyond the link table. *Since the other side might be referenced by other entities on the parent-side, the automatic removal might end up in a `ConstraintViolationException`.*

So, before removing `Role` entity you should be assured that there is no `MyUser` entity linked with this role.